# I am traveling to the Philippines from Tashkent. Do I need a visa to transit in Korea?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, uzbek-citizens

I am an Uzbek citizen traveling to Manila (Philippines) from Tashkent through Seoul Incheon Airport. It’s a self-transfer ticket where I need to collect my baggage and check it in again. Transit time is 3-4 hours.

Do I need a Korean visa?

Answer (score 1):

A transit visa? No. That'd be to stay airside, and if you have to pick up your luggage and check it in again, you'll have to pass through Immigration, entering Korea, then pick up your luggage, pass through Customs, and go up 2 floors to check in again, pass through security, Immigration, and go again to your gate.

Also, there's the issue of terminals. Since Incheon has 2, quite far away from each other, check whether both flights are in the same terminal.

Which means you'll need a tourist visa to do this.

Finally, the fact that it's two tickets and two airlines doesn't necessarily mean you have to do all this. Check with both airlines (which are they?) whether they interline, as is often the case in Asia. This would allow you not to do all this, and stay airside.